# scraping price from the website using python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I tried to **scrape** the price from the website below:
https://www.emma-sleep.com.au/diamond-hybrid/
The price i wanna get should be **674.55**.

Below is my code:

```
web_url = 'https://www.emma-sleep.com.au/diamond-hybrid/'
web_response = requests.get(web_url)
b_soup = BeautifulSoup(web_response.text, 'html.parser')
price=b_soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'installment__full-price'})
price
```

it will return me of a price of 1000 somehow, which is wrong
*[ $1,000.00 ]*

could someone please tell me where i get it wrong?
seems like the price is in the 'script' tage when i checked the html code.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The price is calculated in javascript. For that you need to use an API like [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) that first renders the page in the browser then allows you to access the HTML.

Target html tags:

```
<span class="regular-price text-orange" id="product-price-3853">
   <span class="price" data-price="674.55">$674.55</span>
</span>
```

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

web_url = 'https://www.emma-sleep.com.au/diamond-hybrid/'

s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)

# web driver goes to page
driver.get(web_url)

# to give time for the page to load
driver.implicitly_wait(3)

price = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='regular-price text-orange']/span[@class='price']").text
print(price)
```

Output:

```
$674.55
```

You can also use the XPATH expression:

```
//span[contains(@class, 'regular-price')]/span[@class='price']
```